# Rails text area shows placeholder as text area content in Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-11

I am not sure how this is happening but the placeholder seems to be putting in content in the text area instead of being a placeholder in Internet Explorer v11

Internet Explorer v11

[image: ie_screenshot]

Chrome

[image: chrome_screenshot]

This is the rails text area code

```
= f.text_area :qhse_rules_comment, class: 'form-control audit_area', rows: '2', placeholder: t('.please_enter_comments')
```

How do I make it so that Internet Explorer doesn't use the placeholder as text area content?

Answer (score 0):

Yes IE has this Problem.

You can use the gem 'jquery-placeholder-rails' to solve this problem

https://github.com/navinpeiris/jquery-placeholder-rails

Answer (score 0):

This is a known IE bug which is tracked [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811408/ie10-11-a-textareas-placeholder-text-becomes-its-actual-value-when-using-innertext-innerhtml-or-outerhtml). Using a JS workaround would be your best shot going about this, something like

```
/**
 * Returns a "bug free" html string from a jQuery element. Takes care of an IE (>=10) bug which occurs when a textarea has a placeholder attribute.
 *
 * The problem is when a textarea in IE (>=10) has a placeholder attribute, IE also adds the value of this attribute as text/value to the textarea.
 * Which means that .html() of such an element returns something like <textarea placeholder="foo">foo</textarea> (but should be <textarea placeholder="foo"></textarea>),
 * therefore $($target.html()) would return a textarea which now has value (which is the placeholder)!
 */


var tidyHtml = function($target) {
    var cleanHtml = $target.html(), // variable now contains "buggy" textareas
        badIndizes = [];

    $target.find('textarea[placeholder]').each(function(index, element) {
        if($(element).text() !== $(element).val()) { // there is something in .text(), but no value exists! IE bug! (do NOT use .html() here, because it's escaped -> val() is not escaped)
            badIndizes.push(index);
        }
    });

    if(badIndizes.length > 0) {
        cleanHtml = $(cleanHtml).find('textarea[placeholder]').filter(function(index) {
            return $.inArray(index, badIndizes) > -1;
        }).html('').parents().last().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
    }

    return cleanHtml;
};
```

credit - jamez1414